SMTP Welcome Banner - 220 Message
When my PHP contact form is submitted, I get an error message displayed. Behind the scenes, I know this is from the common 220 welcome SMTP message. Despite it not being an error, my error handling still catches this as an error and unsure why. The email still sends with the entered contact info though.
Modify error handling methods assuming this would help with catching errors. Modify CSS, comment out code blocks for testing purposes, line breakpoints, ask professors familiar with PHP, research for several months.

220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport
unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.

Using godaddy SMTP Settings.
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use Dotenv\Dotenv;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';
// Load environment variables from hashed_smtp_password.env file
try {
    $dotenv = Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Handle the exception or log it
    error_log('Could not load .env file: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
$receiving_email_address = $_ENV['RECEIVING_EMAIL_ADDRESS'];

// Sanitize and validate input data
$from_name = isset($_POST['name']) ? filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS) : '';
$from_email = isset($_POST['email']) ? filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL) : '';
$subject = isset($_POST['subject']) ? filter_var($_POST['subject'], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS) : '';
$message = isset($_POST['message']) ? filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS) : '';

// Validate required fields
if (empty($from_name) || empty($from_email) || empty($subject) || empty($message)) {
    echo 'All fields are required.';
    exit;
}

// Validate email address
if (!filter_var($from_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo 'Invalid email address.';
    exit;
}

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
    // Server settings

    // Enable verbose debug output
    // $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
    $mail->SMTPDebug = false;
    
    // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->isSMTP();             
    
    // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->Host       = $_ENV['HOSTNAME'];    
    // Enable SMTP authentication              
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = $_ENV['SMTP_AUTH'];                    
    // SMTP username               
    $mail->Username   = $_ENV['USERNAME'];     
    // SMTP password       
    $mail->Password   = $_ENV['SMTP_PASSWORD'];     
                    
    $mail->SMTPSecure = $_ENV['SMTPSecure'];  
    // TCP port to connect to
    $mail->Port = $_ENV['Port'];         

    // Recipients
    $mail->setFrom($from_email, $from_name);
    $mail->addAddress($receiving_email_address);             


    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                     // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = nl2br($message);                        // Convert newlines to <br> tags for HTML
    $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($message);                   // Plain text version for non-HTML mail clients

    // Send the email and check for success
    if ($mail->send()) {
        echo '<div style="background-color: green; color: white; padding: 10px;">Message has been sent</div>';
    } 
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ' + $mail->ErrorInfo;
}




What's the exception being caught?

There's a good chance this message is due to the fact that you are setting an arbitrary From address. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24644450/1427878, section titled "Don't use a faux From: sender"

@AlexHowansky, Apologies, there is not a specific exception being caught. I've added an img above. The form data is sent correctly. However, it echos the above message with the error background and the word Error. I cannot seem to find the issue whatsoever.

This code can not generate the string Error: Message has been sent!. Your output is coming from somewhere else. Looks like you may have defined a generic error modal div that should be initialized with display: none and your success message is getting wrapped by it.
